# Fractional numbers' factorial

Tags: factorial

Is there a law or anyway to know the factorial of a fractional number, because as I see the law of factorization `n! = n x (n-1) x (n-2) x ... x 3 x 2 x 1` isn't saying that the number should be an integer. If it does require an integer then shouldn't the law be `[n]! = [n] x ([n]-1) x ([n]-2) x ...`?

Comment: could have been good to check the [wikipedia article about factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial#The_Gamma_and_Pi_functions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check out the [Gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function), an extension of the factorial function to the real (and complex) numbers